# PSWritePDF erroring

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and trying to write a simple script that tests a pdf for having greater than a set number of pages.

Whenever I use Get-PDFDetails, though, it works, but spits out dozens of lines of:

"InvalidOperation: A null key is not allowed in a hash literal."

I feel super out of my depth, what am I doing wrong?

I tried using the command outside of the script with other dfs, it seems that different pdfs cause it to repeat the error message different numbers of times, with a consistent number of times for each pdf, regardless of its location in the file directory. It seems to be correlated to the size of the pdf.

Comment: If you are willing to look into other tools, like `pdfino` or `cpdf` this could be as simple as: `path\cpdf.exe -pages path\a.pdf 2>$null`